# Extract Value from XML file

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

I am trying to get the values from an XML file, like below response. I want to extract the value: 289

```
<operationExecutionResponse>
  <responseCode>0</responseCode>
  <rootContext>
    <stringList name="productIds">
      <string>289</string>
      <string>123</string>
    </stringList>
  </rootContext>
</operationExecutionResponse>
```

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (
r_val,
'//operationExecutionResponse/rootContex/stringList/string[1]')
INTO n_id
FROM DUAL;
```

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (
r_val,
'//operationExecutionResponse/rootContex/stringList/string[@name="productIds"]/text()')
INTO n_id
FROM DUAL;
```

How can I get the value I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt is almost right, but you spelled `rootContext` wrong - it's missing the final `t`. With that corrected that works. (Your second one has the attribute name filter on the wrong node, and would try to return all values not just the first one.)

But `extractvalue()` is deprecated. You can do the same thing with `XMLQuery()`:

```
select XMLQuery(
    '/operationExecutionResponse/rootContext/stringList/string[1]/text()'
    passing r_val
    returning content
  ).getstringval()
into n_id
from dual;
```

or as you seem to be expecting a number:

```
select to_number(
    XMLQuery(
      '/operationExecutionResponse/rootContext/stringList/string[1]/text()'
      passing r_val
      returning content
    ).getstringval()
  )
into n_id
from dual;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f742e0419cebe0c33b7930759a9472b9)

In both cases that will only get the first string/number from the list, which is what your original code did. If you want to get all values you can use `XMLTable()` as @Gnqz showed, but (as you're doing this in a PL/SQL context) you'll need to either select those into a collection or turn it into a cursor query and loop over them - depends what you plan to do with the values once you have them.

As a cursor you might do:

```
for r in (
  select n_id
  from XMLTable(
      '/operationExecutionResponse/rootContext/stringList[@name="productIds"]/string'
    passing r_val
    columns n_id number path '.'
  )
)
loop
  -- do something with the value, as r.n_id here
  dbms_output.put_line('Number: ' || r.n_id);
end loop;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eaf427ab93add4f4da4e12a780ba443e)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH XML_TBL 
AS  (SELECT XMLTYPE('<operationExecutionResponse>
                      <responseCode>0</responseCode>
                      <rootContext>
                        <stringList name="productIds">
                          <string>289</string>
                          <string>123</string>
                        </stringList>
                      </rootContext>
                    </operationExecutionResponse>') XMLDATA
       FROM DUAL)
SELECT VALS
  FROM XML_TBL
     , XMLTABLE(
                  'operationExecutionResponse/rootContext/stringList//*'
                  PASSING XML_TBL.XMLDATA 
                  COLUMNS VALS VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'text()'
                );
```